# FB open graph api, publishing like spotify

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

to explain simply, my site let users to listen music from youtube (totally programmed using client side approach). What i need to implement is a spotify like function in ticker specially when the person is listening to a track.

I have defined 
Action: Catch
Object: Music

What i would like to do is, 
A. publish this in ticker.
Example:

> ABC caught {Sample Music} on Mysite [Box with the link]

B. timeline in the activity block!!

is it possible to redirect the user to Mysite, rather than just to my FB app. 
Also when the user clicks on {sample music}, i would like to redirect it to a particular page .?? is it possible?

As of now, when I click on sample Music, I get redirected to a page a like this:

> http://mysite.com?fb_action_ids=502866955644&fb_action_types=fatslave%3Acatch&fb_source=other_multiline

and actually i need to pass three variables to my site (or my redirected site), lets say Artist, track, videoID, any idea how to go about it.

Comment: Sounds like you want to familiarize yourself with Open Graph actions and objects -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/#actions-objects

Comment: I find myself ok with actions and objects, I amm able to publish but the problem is controlling the redirects on click.

Comment: Well then why don’t you just have your app redirect to your site …?

Comment: app redirects to mysite, but not in a way i want. I want to somehow redirect it to mysite.com/#videoId/artist/track (as i have created a url-routing earlier to interpret it). And given the redirected URl (As shown above in question) has no information regarding the videoId, artist and track, this redirect provides no information.

Comment: Well then you could set some custom action properties when posting the action – and when your site get’s called via the link, you get the action id, and can read out these properties from the posted action instance’s Graph API representation.

Comment: Or, maybe even better: Store the information what object was acted upon (plus other data you might need) in your own database, under the action-instance-id your getting back when publishing an action. Saves you an HTTP request to facebook to decide what to display to a user how followed a link from that action story.

Comment: I was trying on the same line, but dint found a way to get the value of custom action props using graph API representation. Lets say I have the action ID, how do i access the property values?

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with help of Cbroe!!

step 1: create custom action properties (in my case propa,  propb , propc - mark as required)

step 2: when user redirects to ur site with action ID, use action Id to retrieve the custom action properties using GET.

> [more info here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/#read)